# Is there any snowflake data warehouse testing documentation/guide/tutorial and frameworks?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any snowflake data warehouse testing documentation/guide/tutorial?
Can someone plz suggest the course where we can learn how to test snowflake data warehouse?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the Snowflake University courses:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/snowflake-university

Answer (score -1):

Good starting points for learning Snowflake are:

- https://learn.snowflake.com/
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/

In case of testing - are you using any additional tools? Most often they come along with additional database/etl-testing capabilities.

Comment: As of now, I am not aware of any tools and looking for guidance. Plz suggest?